# How to install VirtualBox Guest Addition for Android?

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have *Virtualbox* 5.2.18 and installed Android-x86 4.4

Is there a way to install GuestAddition for Android to ability enable bidirectional clipboard and drag'n'drop?

Android - is Linux, but if I write `VboxLinuxAdditions.run` in console - it gives me an error

> /bin/sh not found

Whenn I try `sh runasroot.sh` - it gives me a message:

> Attempt to execute COMMAND with root privileges, displaying DESCRIPTION if possible and displaying ADVICE if possible if no su(1)-like tool is available

If it was *Windows* I'd just click on '.exe' file, but I don't understand how to do it with Android emulation.

Answer (score 0):

The command itself states there aren't root privileges. So the first thing is to gain root access. But... even in this situation the Android Os is quite different from Linux, so that you'll be able to run a pure Linux command/batch into Android.
Nevertheless we are looking forward to Oracle if they write a code suitable for this purpose (so doubtful).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).